# Permission model

Tags: data-modeling, access-control, erp

I am currently designing a permission model for an ERP.
I came up with two models

**An access level based model**
An access level based model is simply to have per component(Invoicing, Inventory, Accounts etc) read, readwrite, super etc permissions

It is modeled after file permissions.
Each component may have others component's dependencies, so it may affect others.
Should "Reporting" to be a separate category?

**A page/screen based model**
The access level is based on each page,(The editing page, the viewing page, the reporting page etc)
This model will basically generate a huge list of pages, and checkboxes, which I am afraid that it will scare people off.

Answer (score 0):

`Access Level` model is preferred.

If you keep acess permissions together as `Roles` it would be more convenient for users (`Role-Based` at user side maps to `Access-Level` permissions). This way you can encapsulate many of permissions inside a `role` and for example its easy to find out what permissions are needed by an accountant.

Also you can see a page/report (whole of it) as an `access-level` and set permissions (roles) for it in case you need. If you need go in more details and pages are repeated with little differences, split a page into parts (at design level you should think of this) and work at `page-part` level.